# Custom ASP.NET Universal Provider or SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

In an application that has access to a database through a service layer can you create a custom Universal Provider or custom SimpleMembership so that instead of using an EF context that is linked to a database you can overwrite the providers methods to make a service call instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal Provider and SimpleMembership Provider are just implementations of the abstract base class [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). If you wanted to make your own using a service you created you can write your own provider which implements MembershipProvider. You would most likely need to create your own [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) as well as this will be called when you use the [Authorize] attribute on your controllers.

Further information:

[Implementing a membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Implementing a role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Once created you can reference your own providers in your web.config and use them the same way you would use the built in providers